# Why does my recursive function seg fault in C?

Tags: c, recursion

My program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int collatz(int seed, int count) {
    int next = 0;
    if (seed % 2 == 0) {
        next = seed / 2;
    } else {
        next = 3 * seed + 1;
    }
    count++;
    if (next == 1) {
        return count;
    } else {
        return collatz(next, count);
    }
}

int main() {
    int max = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<1000000; i++) {
        int current = collatz(i, 1);
        if (current > max) {
            max = current;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", index);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that recursion normally only goes to a certain depth.  However as far as I can tell I have implemented tail recursion which should stop the seg fault.  If I set i to 100,000 the program runs which leads me to believe the underlying algorithm is correct.  However at one million I get:

> Segmentation fault: 11

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When does it segfault? What does your debugger say?

Comment: Because you blow up the stack with a deep recursion?

Comment: That isn't tail recursion, unless the compiler transforms it into tail recursion. In C, you'd have to use a `while (next != 1)` instead of calling `collatz` at the end.

Comment: Also note that you occasionally get negative values of `next` because of overflow.

Comment: This program has so many branches.. its not surprising that it crashes because it runs out of stack space. The higher you go in number, the greater the branches become.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use a debugger you may find that indeed your function is not tail-recursive.  But why not?  Probably because you simply forgot to enable optimization during compilation.  On my system (GCC on Mac OS), a default build will crash, but building with the `-O3` option will let it run (at least for a lot longer than otherwise; I didn't want to kill my battery testing).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it with 1 million i would say you are probably just running out of stack space causing a segfault

What compiler/os are you using in VS stacksize is 1MB by default but it can be increased.
I am not sure about other compiler/os combinations

Answer (score 0):

**collatz** function is causing the overflow in the middle of a calculation. (it's stack overflow for that).

note:compiler optimization for tail recursion may or may not be done.

use long long (Int64).

```
int collatz(long long seed, int count) {
    long long next = 0;
    if (seed % 2 == 0) {
        next = seed / 2;
    } else {
        next = 3 * seed + 1;
    }
    count++;
    if (next == 1) {
        return count;
    } else {
        return collatz(next, count);
    }
}
```